# How to add elements to a fieldset in magento horizontally rather than vertically

Tags: magento

I am adding few check boxes in to magento using the fieldset option like the following.

```
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('display', array(
        'legend'       => $helper->__('Schedule Sales Order Transfer'),
        'class'        => 'fieldset-wide'
    ));
for($i=01; $i*5<60; $i++){
            $time = $i*5;
            $fieldset->addField('min'.$time, 'checkbox', array( 
                'name' => 'Checkbox', 
                'checked' => false, 
                'onclick' => self::setAll("min"), 
                'onchange' => "", 
                'value' => ''.$time, 
                'disabled' => false, 
                'after_element_html' => '<small>'.$time.'</small>', 
                'tabindex' => 1 
            ));
        }
```

By doing so, all the check boxes are coming one below another. Is it possible to **make it one adjacent to another i.e., horizontally**?

Anybody Please suggest the solution ASAP...

Thank you,

Comment: No there's no way. Magento form elements are rendered out in table rows of table columns for label and input. The only way is to create your own form element, possibly extend Varien_Data_Form_Element_Checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Code return like `<tr>...</tr><tr>..</tr>`, so if you need to add custom `css` or `js` to achieve what you expected,

or

```
for($i=01; $i*5<60; $i++){
            $time[$i]['value'] = $i*5;
            $time[$i]['label'] = $i*5;
        }
        $fieldset->addField('Time', 'checkboxes', array(
            'label' => $this->__('Time'),
            'name' => 'time[]',
            'values' => $time,
            'value'  => '1',
            'tabindex' => 1
        ));
```

its return like `<tr><td>label</td><td>value<ul><li></li>....<li></li></ul></td></tr>`

then you continue your stuff.,

**Note: I'm just suggest the possible ways**

Comment: I didnot understand <tr><td>label</td><td>value<ul><li></li>....<li></li></ul></td></tr> part can you explain littile bit more.... Thank you,

Comment: Where you add a fieldset?

Comment: In to my custom tab in magento admin panel

Comment: then use a inspect element to see return values and you will find why field not align horizontally

Comment: It is so because all these check boxes were added in seperate rows....But how from the code in php can I change it to columns??

Comment: you tried for separate filed to each checkbox and im suggest you for muliti checkboxes with one field

Comment: I am having the same problem even though I change it to multi checkboxes. They are a little bit close now